# Play! Scala: How to disable actor modules loaded at the start of the application when testing?

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, guice

I load some actors at the beginning of my Play! 2.5 application like this:

```
class Module extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport with ScalaModule {
  override def configure() = {
    bindActor[MainSupervisor]("main-supervisor")
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I run my tests I got a lot a logs (and unnecessary calls) from the loaded actor (and the entire cluster and remote system) like

```
[INFO ] a.r.Remoting: Starting remoting 
[INFO ] a.r.Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://application@127.0.0.1:41496] 
[INFO ] a.r.Remoting: Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://application@127.0.0.1:41496]
```

I have, for instance, a class that I test where I don't need any actor, but I don't find any way to disable them (or even better the entire actor system).

What I have tried is:

```
lazy val appWithoutActorsBuilder = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
  .disable[ActorSystem]
  .disable[MainSupervisor]
  .build()
lazy val injectorWithoutActors = appWithoutActorsBuilder.injector
lazy val wSClientWithoutActors = injectorWithoutActors.instanceOf[WSClient]
lazy val ec = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
lazy val facebookAPI = new FacebookAPI(wSClientWithoutActors, ec)
```

But when I test the FacebookAPI methods (e.g. `facebookAPI.method(...) mustBe ...`) I still see the logs from Akka. What can I do in order to avoid it?

Comment: Have you tried configuring log4j / logstash to not output Info level logs for classes in that package?

Comment: Those are info logs so one more way is just to make your log level configurable (in `application.conf`) and then pass a higher level for test.

Comment: @BruceLowe I don't want not to ouput Info level logs.

Comment: @NaderHadjiGhanbari The only way I know in order to do that is to load an other log configuration file when sbt starts and I don't want to do that each time. Moreover, this application call other services when it starts, and I don't want this to happen when I test it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to disable your module instead of your actor. So, considering that you have this class:

```
package com.acme.modules

class Module extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport with ScalaModule {
  override def configure() = {
    bindActor[MainSupervisor]("main-supervisor")
  }
}
```

And that you are registering it at your `conf/application.conf` like this:

```
play.modules.enabled += "com.acme.modules.Module"
```

Then, at your tests, your have to do the following:

```
lazy val appWithoutActorsBuilder = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
  .disable[com.acme.modules.Module]
  .build()
```

Comment: Thanks, it really disables MainSupervisor. But, I still have two problems: the actor system is still loaded (not a big deal) and I have some errors because no implementation is bound for MainSupervisor (I know that) although I don't use it in the class I am testing (i.e FacebookAPI). How can it be possible?

Comment: If you use GuiceInjectorBuilder akka system wont be loaded.